# Setting Xamarin UITableViewCellStyle while using IntPtr constructor for cell reuse

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

As per [this Xamarin docs page](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/), I'm building a table view in a Xamarin iOS app:

- Custom `UITableViewSource` class, overriding `GetCell()`, `NumberOfSections()` and `RowsInSection()`
- Custom `UITableViewCell`, implementing the constructor that takes `IntPtr` to enable cell reuse
- Calling `myTableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse()` in the view controller, giving it the type of my custom `UITableViewCell`

This seems to work. However, I want to use cells with a non-default styling. As [the next page in the docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_3_-_customizing_a_table%27s_appearance/) explains, there are a few options for `UITableViewCellStyle`, and I'd like to use `UITableViewCellStyle.Value2`. Now, `UITableViewCell` has a constructor that takes a `UITableViewCellStyle` option, but I can't use that because the cell reuse requires me to implement the `IntPtr` constructor, and I don't see anything that's accessible from *inside* that constructor that I can use to set the style.

Is there a way to select a different `UITableViewCellStyle` option without using the `UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle style, NSString reuseIdentifier)` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to load a different UITableViewCellStyle option without using the UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle style, NSString reuseIdentifier) constructor. This constructor loads the underlying XIB.

You mentioned "non-default styling", using your own custom UITableViewCell would give you freedom to design your layout as you require, adding labels, images etc. Create a public method inside the CustomUITableViewCell, and you can then define how to display the content, as documented below.

**UITableView**

```
public class CustomTableView : UITableView
{
    static readonly NSString MyCellId = new NSString ("CustomTableViewCell");

    public CustomTableView ()
    {
        RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(CustomTableViewCell), MyCellId);
        Source = new CustomDataSource();
    }
}
```

**UITableViewCell**

```
public class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public CustomTableViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {}

    public Load(object[] data){

        //Create custom view in code

        var title = new UILabel();

        // etc.

        // Or pull in from an XIB

        UINib Nib = UINib.FromName ("CustomViewCell_iPad", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    }
}
```

**UITableViewSource**

```
public class CustomTableDataSource : UITableViewSource
{

    private NSString MyCellId { get; set; }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (CustomTableViewCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell (MyCellId, indexPath);
        cell.load(sampleData[indexPath.row]);
        return cell;
    }
}
```